# HDFS Erasure Coding File Creation

Tags: hdfs, erasure-code

I am looking for a way to create a file (e.g. using copyFromLocal) in Apache HDFS and set the Erasure Coding policy in the process.

According to [this page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSErasureCoding.html), I can use `hdfs ec --setPolicy -path <folder> -policy  RS-6-3-1024k` to set the policy for a directory and its children. Is there a way to set the policy for a file when I create it, independent of the policy of the parent?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is currently no way to do this in the HDFS client v3.0.0 beta.